# php form submit to sql while loop

Tags: php

can u make this code more better. This shopping cart data posted how to insert to database it is working well but limited and huge code who can make shorten?
i put this code will going morethan 5 $x++ how do smart and short code do more function.

```
$ina_1 = $_POST['item_name_1']; $iq_1 = $_POST['quantity_1']; $ipr_1 = $_POST['amount_1'];$qp_1= $iq_1*$ipr_1;
$ina_2 = $_POST['item_name_2']; $iq_2 = $_POST['quantity_2']; $ipr_2 = $_POST['amount_2'];$qp_2= $iq_2*$ipr_2;
$ina_3 = $_POST['item_name_3']; $iq_3 = $_POST['quantity_3']; $ipr_3 = $_POST['amount_3'];$qp_3= $iq_3*$ipr_3;
$ina_4 = $_POST['item_name_4']; $iq_4 = $_POST['quantity_4']; $ipr_4 = $_POST['amount_4'];$qp_4= $iq_4*$ipr_4;
$ina_5 = $_POST['item_name_5']; $iq_5 = $_POST['quantity_5']; $ipr_5 = $_POST['amount_5'];$qp_5= $iq_5*$ipr_5;


$shipping = $_POST['shipping'];
$tprice = $qp_1+$qp_2+$qp_3+$qp_4+$qp_5+$qp_6+$qp_7+$qp_8+$qp_9+$shipping;
if(empty($idu)){
$guestid = rand(111111,999999);
}
$orderid = rand(111111,999999);
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ina_1, $matches); $look1=  $matches[0]; $sl_1 = $look1[0];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ina_2, $matches); $look2=  $matches[0]; $sl_2 = $look2[0];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ina_3, $matches); $look3=  $matches[0]; $sl_3 = $look3[0];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ina_4, $matches); $look4=  $matches[0]; $sl_4 = $look4[0];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ina_5, $matches); $look5=  $matches[0]; $sl_5 = $look5[0];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO d_order 
            (`userid`,`orderid`,`sellerid`,`item`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`tprice`,`date`,`status`)
   VALUES ('$idu','$orderid','$sl_1','$ina_1','$iq_1','$ipr_1','$qp_1','$tprice','$now','0')") or die(mysql_error());
if(!empty($ina_2)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO d_order 
            (`userid`,`orderid`,`sellerid`,`item`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`tprice`,`date`,`status`)
VALUES ('$idu','$orderid','$sl_2','$ina_2','$iq_2','$ipr_2','$qp_2','$tprice','$now','0')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if(!empty($ina_3)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO d_order 
            (`userid`,`orderid`,`sellerid`,`item`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`tprice`,`date`,`status`)
VALUES ('$idu','$orderid','$sl_3','$ina_3','$iq_3','$ipr_3','$qp_3','$tprice','$now','0')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if(!empty($ina_4)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO d_order 
            (`userid`,`orderid`,`sellerid`,`item`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`tprice`,`date`,`status`)
VALUES ('$idu','$orderid','$sl_4','$ina_4','$iq_4','$ipr_4','$qp_4','$tprice','$now','0')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if(!empty($ina_5)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO d_order 
            (`userid`,`orderid`,`sellerid`,`item`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`tprice`,`date`,`status`)
VALUES ('$idu','$orderid','$sl_5','$ina_5','$iq_5','$ipr_5','$qp_5','$tprice','$now','0')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: all you need to know is the maximum possible number of items & then use a variable to loop from 1 to x e.g. instead of $_POST['item_name_5'] use $_POST['item_name_'.$x] within the loop. Or, better, have your values submitted as arrays which you can loop through. As an aside, you run the risk of duplicate order IDs by generating them randomly - why not use a database sequence to keep track of order IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally untested but I think, with some tweaking perhaps, the following might simplify things for you.

```
<?php
    $max_number_products=5;
    $shipping = $_POST['shipping'];
    $cart = array();

    for( $i=1; $i <= $max_number_products; $i++ ){
        $name=$_POST[ 'item_name_'.$i ];
        $qty=$_POST[ 'quantity_'.$i ];
        $amount=$_POST[ 'amount_'.$i ];
        $price = abs( $qty * $amount );

        $cart[]=array( 
            'name'      =>  $name,
            'amount'    =>  $amount,
            'quantity'  =>  $qty,
            'price'     =>  $price
        );
        $cart['total']+=$price;
    }
    $tprice = $cart['total'] + $shipping;
    /* 
       what is $idu? where is it used? 
       Should it not be $guestid in the 
       sql query not $idu which MAY be empty!
    */
    if( empty( $idu ) ) $guestid = rand( 111111, 999999 );
    $orderid = rand( 111111, 999999 );

    foreach( $cart as $key => $cartitem ){
        preg_match_all( '!\d+!', $cartitem['name'], $matches );
        $look1 = $matches[0];
        $sl_1  = $look1[0];

        $sql="INSERT INTO `d_order`
                ( `userid`, `orderid`, `sellerid`, `item`, `quantity`, `amount`, `total`, `tprice`, `date`, `status`) VALUES
                ( '$idu', '$orderid', '$sl_1', '{$cartitem['name']}', '{$cartitem['quantity']}', '{$cartitem['amount']}', '{$cartitem['price']}', '$tprice', now(), '0')";

        echo '<pre>',$sql,'</pre>';
        /* 
        mysql_query( $sql );
        */
    }
?>
```

Comment: if insert became 6 row and the 6th is empty the following `sellerid`, `item`, `quantity`, `amount`, `total` can you help me and thank you very much i have another code question i will send u

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but try changing `$max_number_products` to 6??

Comment: look this the output the second is empty

Comment: i mean i change '$max_number_products=5' in to 2 but the output increase in 3 . 3rd is empty unnecessary row added. in other word max number is increase in to 6 the row became 7, 1->2, 2->3 adding empty row automatically. i believe u understand. viber +1401 402 0325

Comment: i fix this problem `$cart['total']+=$price;` into `$total +=$price;`  now working fine tks @RAMRAIDER

Answer (score -1):

You should use loop statements for this. If you can get a count of items in your cart, then doing something like this might help.

```
$curr_item = 0; // and $tot_item is the total number of items.
while($curr_item<$tot_item)
{
$itemlist['curr_item'.$curr_item] = $_POST['item_name_'.$curr_item];
$curr_item++;
}
```

And I think, that you can use the same concept for other conditional statements as well.

Comment: I would have appreciated if I were given a chance to make myself clear, before down voting.